# Is it possible to use conditional operator in checkbox using flex?

Tags: php, apache-flex, air, flash

I want to fill color based on condition so I used conditional operator for the checkbox. But it's shows the error `Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type Array`. What did I do wrong ? How can I dynamically change the color of a checkbox ?

```
<mx:CheckBox id="home" enabled="false"  fillColors="{(data.actualwin != '1') ? 
    '[#8CE912,#8CE912]' : '[#8CE912,#8CE912]'}"  selected="{data.betting_home=='1'}"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
'[#8CE912,#8CE912]'
```

with

```
["#8CE912","#8CE912"]
```

or

```
[0x8CE912,0x8CE912]
```

(remove quotes)

You pass a string ('[#8CE912,#8CE912]') into a property where an array is expected

Comment: thanks artemb . i found the problem
fillColors="{[(data.actualwin == '2') ?'#66ff00' : '#ffffff']}"

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use an ItemRenderer